# Angular 2 Component : Reflecting data in Interpolations :

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to UI development and working on an application in Angular 2. Currently, I have a requirement like, I need to make a service call and populate few values on my component. So, I defined a service and fetched data from a node.js service. This much part is working fine. I did write the code to fetch the values from service in ngOnInit() lifecycle hook. And displaying this values using {{}} String interpolation. But unfortunately, the data fetched from the service is not getting updated in the Component UI. (Values are getting displayed on console.log)

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Typescript Code :

export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  COUNT1 : number = 0;
  COUNT2 : number = 0;
  COUNT3 : number = 0;

  constructor(private countService : SubconsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subconsService.getCurrentStats().subscribe(
      (data : any) => {
        this.COUNT1 = data.count1;
      }
    );
  }
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTML Code :

COUNT :: <span class="badge">{{COUNT1}}</span></i></b>
```

Comment: are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: It's because the data is coming back as asynchronous. Try changing it to ´this.COUNTData = data` and change your interpolation to ´{{COUNTData?.count1}}´. The ´?´ operator will wait for the asynch data to come back